# map pandas values to a categorical level

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas.  R users use the split, apply, combine pattern for analyzing sub-populations.  e.g. gender, 1='Male', 2='Female', 9='Unknown.

I have a dataframe with a day column whose 20,000+ value's are ints 1 to 7, corresponding to 'Mon', 'Tue', etc.  I need categories using labels and not their original int values.

My first attempt is trying .astype("category"):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
dow = pd.DataFrame({'labels': ("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday",\
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday")})

data = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0]})
data['formtatted'] = dow['labels'].astype('category')
data

value   formtatted
0   1   Sunday
1   1   Monday
2   2   Tuesday
3   3   Wednesday
4   4   Thursday
5   7   Friday
6   8   Saturday
7   9   NaN
8   0   NaN
```

I'm expected the labels to map to the integer values giving 'Sunday' twice and instead a get the behavior of a re-cycled list.

Next I try the .factorize attribute like:

```
data2 = pd.DataFrame({'values': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0]})
dow2 = pd.DataFrame({'labels': ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday", \
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]})
dow_cat = pd.factorize(dow2['labels'])

dow_cat
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 Index(['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
    'Saturday'], dtype='object'))
```

Looks promising.

```
data2['labels'] = dow_cat[0]
```

but raises the error: Length of values does not match length of index

More searching turns up:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/source/categorical.rst#differences-to-rs-factor

stating:  It's not possible to specify labels at creation time. Use s.cat.rename_categories(new_labels) afterwards.

fair enough:

```
dow3 = pd.DataFrame({'values': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]},
               dtype="category")

dow3.values = dow3['values'].cat.rename_categories(["Sunday", \
"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday", \
"Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"])
df3['formatted'] = dow3["values"]

df3

    values  formatted
0   1   Sunday
1   1   Monday
2   2   Tuesday
3   3   Wednesday
4   4   Thursday
5   7   Friday
6   8   Saturday
7   9   NaN
8   0   NaN
```

Which where I started, with the behavior of a re-cycled list.

I'm betting I've overlooked the obvious, but it eludes me.  Suggestions on where I go from here?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 12):

Not sure I'm understanding what you are trying to do... Maybe you are overcomplicating something easy: is this what you want? If not please provide a clear example with input and expected output.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'values': [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 0]})
dow = {
    0:"Sunday",
    1:"Monday",
    2:"Tuesday",
    3:"Wednesday", 
    4:"Thursday", 
    5:"Friday", 
    6:"Saturday"
}
data["dow"] = data['values'].map(dow)

print data
```

result:

```
   values        dow
0       1     Monday
1       1     Monday
2       2    Tuesday
3       3  Wednesday
4       4   Thursday
5       7        NaN
6       8        NaN
7       9        NaN
8       0     Sunday
```

Comment: Thank you, Julien.  This is the behavior I am looking for.